# Is image cropping possible in an Android app?

Tags: android, image, scaling

Is it possible to crop an image on Android?

For example:

If the image must fit in a 400w x 400h space and it is 600w x 400h, can you horizontally center align it within the 400w x 400h placeholder space and crop out 100 pixels on the left and 100 pixels on the right.

OR

If the image must fit in a 400w x 400h space and it is 400w x 600h, can you vertically center align it to the image placeholder and crop out 100 pixels on the top and 100 pixels on the bottom.

This may also apply to images of many different resolutions coming in from a server - regardless of the resolution of the image, can you accomplish the above?

I found this but this is specifically for users to be able to crop their images manually in the app (https://medium.com/mindorks/android-top-image-cropper-libraries-3bc4a4f8f2df), but I need to have the image pull in to a set placeholder size in the app from the API.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes it is possible to auto crop/resize/flip/rotate/filter and otherwise manipulate an image (Bitmap) on Android. StackOverFlow has literally thousands of example questions and answers (not to mention the [github](https://github.com/)).

Comment: Thank you Jon. I did search for answers here, but wasn't able to find something that answered my question specifically. Any thoughts on what to search for or any good links you can point me to on how to do this. Our developer doesn't know how.